# FCM notifications suddenly stopped working in iOS Cordova app

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

FCM messages were being delivered to the iOS app 2 days back. But since yesterday, we're getting a strange error when the app is run directly on device through Xcode. **App that s already there on AppStore is receiving push notifications**.

Plugin Used: cordova-plugin-firebase

FCM Server returns below error:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "messaging/registration-token-not-registered",
        "message": "The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages."
      }
    },
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "messaging/registration-token-not-registered",
        "message": "The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons. See the error documentation for more details. Remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages."
      }
    }
  ],
  "canonicalRegistrationTokenCount": 0,
  "failureCount": 2,
  "successCount": 0,
  "multicastId": 6313090191389462000
}
```

Xcode version: Version 10.0 (10A255)

Getting similar when a notification is triggered through Firebase Console
[image: Firebase Console]

Comment: Is your app connecting to your firebase account ? There was a step where it told you if you are initialising firebase correctly. Not sure about this exact error, but there are quite a few things that can go wrong.

Comment: Issue was with Xcode version 10.0 (10A255). After downgrading Xcode to Version 9.4.1 (9F2000) Notifications are working fine.